# Acrobat DC 2021 edition and Photoshop 2020 v21 miss UI fonts

Tags: wine, fonts, 21.04, adobe

I found a way to make Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2021 and Photoshop 2020 v21 work on Ubuntu 21.04 with Wine. However, both applications seem to be missing the fonts for their entire UI.

Here is how Adobe Acrobat Reader looks like:

[image: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2021 missing UI fonts]

I have tried to copy some fonts from it in different system locations, but it doesn't work.

Do I need some regkey? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I was missing the Segoe-UI fonts on Linux, which I  installed as described in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux):

> Open `terminal` and run the command below
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux/master/install.sh
> chmod +x install.sh
> ./install.sh
> ```